# Cant seem to scrape with website with PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, html, web-scraping

I am new to scraping website and I was interested in getting the ticket prices from this website.
https://www.cheaptickets.com/events/tickets/firefly-music-festival-4-day-pass-2867495
I see the ticket prices in the p#price-selected-label.filters-selected-label tag, but I cant seem to access it. I tried a few things and looked at a few tutorials, but either I get a blank returned or some error. The code is based off http://blog.endpoint.com/2016/07/scrape-web-content-with-php-no-api-no.html

```
    <?php
 
require('simple_html_dom.php');
 
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('https://www.cheaptickets.com/events/tickets/firefly-music-festival-4-day-pass-2867495');
 
// creating an array of elements
$videos = [];
 
// Find top ten videos
$i = 1;
        $videoDetails = $html->find('p#price-selected-label.filters-selected-label')-> innertext;

//        $videoDetails = $html->find('p#price-selected-label.filters-selected-label',0);



echo $videoDetails;
/*
foreach ($html->find('li.expanded-shelf-content-item-wrapper') as $video) {
        if ($i > 10) {
                break;
        }
 
        // Find item link element 
        $videoDetails = $video->find('a.yt-uix-tile-link', 0);
 
        // get title attribute
        $videoTitle = $videoDetails->title;
 
        // get href attribute
        $videoUrl = 'https://youtube.com' . $videoDetails->href;
 
        // push to a list of videos
        $videos[] = [
                'title' => $videoTitle,
                'url' => $videoUrl
        ];
 
        $i++;
}
 
var_dump($videos);
*/
```

Comment: Websites sometimes use javascript to populate to website with content.

Comment: do you have to use php for this ?

Comment: no, I don't need to use php, I am just most comfortable with it, but I have no problem of using something else if it would work better. Thanks

Comment: i usually use `PhantomJs` for this kind of stuff, it will grab the whole page and you can use jquery to select the element you want and return it to php,

Comment: Reporting a blank page or "some error" is not part of a useful question. Provide actual error messages in your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can't get it because javascript renders it, so it's not available in the original html that your library get.

**Use phantomjs(will execute javascript);**

1. Download [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) and place the executable in a path that your PHP binary can reach.
2. Place the following 2 files in the same directory:

**get-website.php**

```
<?php

    $phantom_script= dirname(__FILE__). '/get-website.js';     

    $response =  exec ('phantomjs ' . $phantom_script);

    echo  htmlspecialchars($response);
?>
```

**get-website.js**

```
    var webPage = require('webpage');
    var page = webPage.create();    

    page.open('https://www.cheaptickets.com/events/tickets/firefly-music-festival-4-day-pass-2867495', function(status) {
        if (status === "success") {
            page.includeJs('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js', function() {          
                var myElem = $('p#price-selected-label.filters-selected-label');
                console.log(myElem);
            });

            phantom.exit();         
        }
    });
```

3. Browse to get-website.php and the target site, https://www.cheaptickets.com/events/tickets/firefly-music-festival-4-day-pass-2867495 contents will return after executing inline javascript. You can also call this from a command line using php /path/to/get-website.php.

Comment: Thank you for the info, going to try it out!